# Select most recent value each given day, based on the latest updated timestamp

Tags: sql

For my data depicted below, I need to edit my SQL so that for each given day ('gas_date') I need to select only a single row for each day where this row has the most recent 'LastUpdated' value which I have highlighted in yellow below.

[image: Data]

I tried the following sql, however this only selects the max value for LastUpdated from the entire dataset over the entire gas_date range, rather than the max LastUpdated value from each gas day.

```
SELECT gas_date, pipeline_point_name, value, LastUpdated from table12
WHERE LastUpdated = (SELECT MAX(LastUpdated) FROM table12)
```

Comment: No one can read that image. You need to edit the question to use **formatted text** instead.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Sorry about that hopefully that is clearer now

Comment: Nope... still an image. If you're taking a screen shot, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 1):

SELECT gas_date, pipeline_point_name, value, LastUpdated
from table12
WHERE LastUpdated in
(
SELECT MAX(LastUpdated)
FROM table12 group by gas_date
)

Subquery returns the Latest Lastupdated date for each day